# Android - database connectivity with MS-SQL 2005

Tags: android, jdbc

I have a Query regarding SQL2005 and android database connectivity.
I m try to make a connection , but an error is occurring.i.e

> Could not find class 'javax.sql.XAConnection', referenced from method
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.poolCloseEventNotify

before this i have included the requird Jdbc-sql driver (i.e sqljdbc4)